# Trino Connector Per Schema Credentials

Tags: trino

It looks like Trino enforces access based control just before calling a target datasource via a configured connector. Specifically, for example for MySQL connector I need to put the "connection-user" and the "connection-password" properties which (given that I want to keep a single mysql catalog and use different schemas) really require to put a user that has an access to all schemas.

Isn't it a security breach? Is there any way to tell Trino to **forward** credentials that clients use to connect to Trino itself.

Thanks in advance.